# Programming language for video

Tags: video, latex

As a big-fan of latex/PDF, I am looking for counterpart in video world. More specifically, latex can used to produce document, slides, and vector graphics in PDF format, which is essentially lossless and can be converted into other formats. Is there any programming language which can produce a "vector graphical" video in certain standard file format, which can convert to other video formats.

For video, it is better to be able to add sound track(.mp3).

Comment: You could have a look at animated svg, they can directly be produced from latex via `dvisvgm` (have a look at the media4svg package for sound options)

Comment: For examples how to produce traditional mp4 videos with latex, have a look at https://github.com/TikZlings

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with it, but here is the library the math youtuber 3blue1brown created to animate his math videos [github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/). I only know that it exists but have no experience with it.

Comment: Closed because... **(1)** As you can see your question produces no real **programming answer**, just a bunch of comments that act like adverts for other products. Adverts are considered **spam** on StackOverflow. **(2)** There is no _"programming language for video"_. Instead you write video data (pixels) using an encoder in your preferred language. An image/audio/video format encoder cannot also be a programming language.